# Monitor the progress of a spring batch job

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am writing various jobs using spring batch with java configuration.

I need to get the current state of the job
e.g. 
which steps are currently running (I may have multiple steps running at the same time)
Which steps failed (the status and exit code)
etc.

The only examples I see online are of XML based spring batch and I want to use java config only.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you setup the DB for yours jobs?
Because you could read all this information in the spring batch tables

Comment: Yes, but I was thinking using native spring batch code would be a better option. your thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use [JobExplorer](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/explore/JobExplorer.html)

> Entry point for browsing executions of running or historical jobs and steps. Since the data may be re-hydrated from persistent storage, it may not contain volatile fields that would have been present when the execution was active.

```
List<JobExecution> jobExecutions = jobExplorer.getJobExecutions(jobInstance);
for (JobExecution jobExecution : jobExecutions) {
    jobExecution.getStepExecutions();
    //read step info
 }
```

And for create jobExplorer you have to use the factory:

```
import org.springframework.batch.core.explore.support.JobExplorerFactoryBean;
JobExplorerFactoryBean factory = new JobExplorerFactoryBean();
factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
factory.getObject();
```

Answer (score 0):

I use these two queries on spring batch meta data tables to know about job progress and step details.

```
SELECT * FROM BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION ORDER BY START_TIME DESC;

SELECT * FROM BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION WHERE JOB_EXECUTION_ID=? ORDER BY STATUS;
```

With First query, I first find `JOB_EXECUTION_ID`  corresponding to my job execution then use that id in second query to find details about specific steps.

Additionally, your config choice ( Java or XML ) has nothing to do with Spring Batch meta data. If you are persisting data then it doesn't matter if its XML config or Java Config.

For Java based monitoring- you can use `JobExplorer` & `JobRepository`  beans to query jobs etc.

e.g. `List<JobInstance>` from `jobExplorer.getJobInstances` & `jobExplorer.getJobExecutions(jobInstance)` etc.

From JobExecutions you can get StepExecutions and so on.

You might have to set `JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor` bean like below for `JobExplorer` & `JobRepository` to work properly.

```
@Bean
    public JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor(
        JobRegistry jobRegistry) {
    JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor = new JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor();
    jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor.setJobRegistry(jobRegistry);
    return jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you.

I was thinking more in the lines of spring batch native java code to do these tests.